# Dynamic renaming of Columns based on row values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to rename columns of a new table based on the row values of a table.

I am using a cursor to fetch the column values corresponding to the old table name. Then altering the newly created table to rename the columns by using the values fetched by the cursor.

The following table shows the columns to be remapped from the client_label to master_label for the respective client_id.

```
CREATE TABLE `mapping_table` (
`_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`master_label` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`client_label` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`org_label` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`client_id` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `mapping_table` (`_id`, `master_label`, `client_label`, 
`organization_label`, `client_id`) VALUES
(1, 'CUST-ID', 'client', 'TEST', 'tes'),
(8, 'TRANSACTION-ID', 'trno', 'TEST', 'tes'),
(9, 'TRANSACTION-DATE', 'date', 'TEST', 'tes'),
(14, 'PROD-NAME', 'product', 'TEST', 'rbb'),
(16, 'SALES-FIRSTNAME', 'firstname', 'TEST', 'tes')
;
```

The Procedure looks like this..

```
    BEGIN

DECLARE old_names varchar(50) default null;
DECLARE new_names varchar(50) default null;
DECLARE num_cols varchar(3) DEFAULT null;
DECLARE i INT(3) DEFAULT null;
DECLARE cur_old_names CURSOR for SELECT client_label from`mapping_table` where client_id = ip_client_id order by _id;

DECLARE cur_new_names CURSOR for SELECT master_label from `mapping_table` where client_id = ip_client_id order by _id;
BEGIN
if ip_client_id = (SELECT DISTINCT(client_id) from `mapping_table` where client_id = ip_client_id) THEN
    CREATE TABLE `test01`
    SELECT * FROM `ROOT_TABLE`;

select count(client_id) into num_cols from `mapping_table` where client_id=ip_client_id;


DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

-- open the cursor
OPEN cur_old_names;
OPEN cur_new_names;

my_loop: LOOP
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_new_names INTO val1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_old_names INTO val2;

    IF done THEN -- this will be true when we are out of rows to read, so we go to the statement after END LOOP.
        LEAVE my_loop; 
    ELSE 
        ALTER TABLE `test01 ` change val1 val2 varchar(50);
    END IF;
END LOOP;   

close cur_old_names;
close cur_new_names;
end if;
END;
END
```

The test01 table should contain column names from the cursor cur_new_names fetched into val2

While executing, I get the error message,

```
 The following query has failed: "SET @p0='tes'; CALL 
 `map_column_names`(@p0); "MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column 'val1' in 'test01_normalized_02'
```